# Django deploy on Heroku gives site can't be reached response

Tags: django, heroku, deployment, heroku-postgres

I’m having a tough time deploying my django app (v1.9) to heroku (psql 9.5),cedar stack-14.

Here’s how I arrived here: I had tremendous migration issues that resulted in “””django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation already exists”””, and “””Django column “name” of relation “django_content_type” does not exist””” errors. Figuring that there were old, mishandled migrations imported int django_migrations table, I decided to push a fresh, local db up to an empty heroku with:

```
PGUSER=dbnameHERE PGPASSWORD=dbpassHERE heroku pg:push localDBnameHERE DATABASE --app appnameHERE
```

This worked flawlessly. After that, here’s what happens when I run these commands:

When I run heroku local, my full app shows locally on 0.0.0.0:5000. (/admin works, but with css issues, presumably bc the whitenoise module I imported does not deal well under production .env settings)

When I run heroku local -e .env.DEV (development .env settings) on 0.0.0.0:5000, everything, including /admin works wonderfully.

The issue begins when gunicorn comes into the picture. When I run gunicorn config.wsgi:application, it runs, but I get “This site can’t be reached, localhost took too long to respond” blank page.

Here is the request header from the blank webpage:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Connection: keep-alive
Server: gunicorn/19.4.5
Date: Tue, 07 Jun 2016 22:39:00 GMT
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Location: https://sitename.herokuapp.com/
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Xss-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Via: 1.1 vegur
```

When I run heroku - heroku run python manage.py check --deploy, I get this:

```
WARNINGS:
?: (security.W001) You do not have 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware' in your MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES so the SECURE_HSTS_SECONDS, SECURE_CONTENT_TYPE_NOSNIFF, SECURE_BROWSER_XSS_FILTER, and SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT settings will have no effect.
?: (security.W009) Your SECRET_KEY has less than 50 characters or less than 5 unique characters. Please generate a long and random SECRET_KEY, otherwise many of Django's security-critical features will be vulnerable to attack.
?: (security.W012) SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE is not set to True. Using a secure-only session cookie makes it more difficult for network traffic sniffers to hijack user sessions.
?: (security.W016) You have 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware' in your MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES, but you have not set CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE to True. Using a secure-only CSRF cookie makes it more difficult for network traffic sniffers to steal the CSRF token.
?: (security.W017) You have 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware' in your MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES, but you have not set CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY to True. Using an HttpOnly CSRF cookie makes it more difficult for cross-site scripting attacks to steal the CSRF token.
?: (security.W018) You should not have DEBUG set to True in deployment.
?: (security.W019) You have 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware' in your MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES, but X_FRAME_OPTIONS is not set to 'DENY'. The default is 'SAMEORIGIN', but unless there is a good reason for your site to serve other parts of itself in a frame, you should change it to 'DENY'.
?: (security.W020) ALLOWED_HOSTS must not be empty in deployment.

System check identified 8 issues (0 silenced).
```

Same blank page and 301 redirect with no error code when I navigate to sitename.herokuapp.com that I got when running gunicorn. Any guess as to why my app throws redirects when gunicorn gets involved?

Comment: as an aside, many of the warnings are not correct, ie ALLOWED_HOSTS is set to ['*'] in env vars, and DEBUG is set to False. Does this mean changes to env vars is not getting picked up when I git push to heroku?

Answer (score 0):

I eventually solved this issue by re-reading the [Heroku docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars), where it states that production environments must have their config vars loaded separately, either through their dashboard interface, or by using their `heroku config:set` command from the heroku cli.

I had placed my config vars $VIRTUAL_ENV/bin/postactivate, loading the different virtualenv configs following activation of the virtualenv; however, that file was not being used in production.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ENVIRONMENT == 'production':
   SECURE_BROWSER_XSS_FILTER = True
   X_FRAME_OPTIONS = 'DENY'
   SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = True
   SECURE_HSTS_SECONDS = 3600
   SECURE_HSTS_INCLUDE_SUBDOMAINS = True
   SECURE_HSTS_PRELOAD = True
   SECURE_CONTENT_TYPE_NOSNIFF = True
   SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True 
   CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
```

There is some security issues can be happen